# Print a conversion table for (un)signed bytes

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, integer

Your task: Print or return a conversion table with every byte from `00` to `ff`'s value as an unsigned integer, to its value as a signed one (using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

For example:

```
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
15    15
16    16
17    17
18    18
19    19
20    20
21    21
22    22
23    23
24    24
25    25
26    26
27    27
28    28
29    29
30    30
31    31
32    32
33    33
34    34
35    35
36    36
37    37
38    38
39    39
40    40
41    41
42    42
43    43
44    44
45    45
46    46
47    47
48    48
49    49
50    50
51    51
52    52
53    53
54    54
55    55
56    56
57    57
58    58
59    59
60    60
61    61
62    62
63    63
64    64
65    65
66    66
67    67
68    68
69    69
70    70
71    71
72    72
73    73
74    74
75    75
76    76
77    77
78    78
79    79
80    80
81    81
82    82
83    83
84    84
85    85
86    86
87    87
88    88
89    89
90    90
91    91
92    92
93    93
94    94
95    95
96    96
97    97
98    98
99    99
100   100
101   101
102   102
103   103
104   104
105   105
106   106
107   107
108   108
109   109
110   110
111   111
112   112
113   113
114   114
115   115
116   116
117   117
118   118
119   119
120   120
121   121
122   122
123   123
124   124
125   125
126   126
127   127
128   -128
129   -127
130   -126
131   -125
132   -124
133   -123
134   -122
135   -121
136   -120
137   -119
138   -118
139   -117
140   -116
141   -115
142   -114
143   -113
144   -112
145   -111
146   -110
147   -109
148   -108
149   -107
150   -106
151   -105
152   -104
153   -103
154   -102
155   -101
156   -100
157   -99
158   -98
159   -97
160   -96
161   -95
162   -94
163   -93
164   -92
165   -91
166   -90
167   -89
168   -88
169   -87
170   -86
171   -85
172   -84
173   -83
174   -82
175   -81
176   -80
177   -79
178   -78
179   -77
180   -76
181   -75
182   -74
183   -73
184   -72
185   -71
186   -70
187   -69
188   -68
189   -67
190   -66
191   -65
192   -64
193   -63
194   -62
195   -61
196   -60
197   -59
198   -58
199   -57
200   -56
201   -55
202   -54
203   -53
204   -52
205   -51
206   -50
207   -49
208   -48
209   -47
210   -46
211   -45
212   -44
213   -43
214   -42
215   -41
216   -40
217   -39
218   -38
219   -37
220   -36
221   -35
222   -34
223   -33
224   -32
225   -31
226   -30
227   -29
228   -28
229   -27
230   -26
231   -25
232   -24
233   -23
234   -22
235   -21
236   -20
237   -19
238   -18
239   -17
240   -16
241   -15
242   -14
243   -13
244   -12
245   -11
246   -10
247   -9
248   -8
249   -7
250   -6
251   -5
252   -4
253   -3
254   -2
255   -1
```

**Formatting:**

- The output doesn't have to be padded to nicely line up like it does above (just a space in between would be fine)
- The separators can be any two strings which can't be confused for the data or each other
- Any base can be used (but if using binary, `-1` would be `-00000001`, not `11111111`)
- Trailing (and/or leading) whitespace and separators are allowed
- The output must be in the correct order
- **The output must be textual; returning arrays/lists/dictionaries is not allowed**

**Valid outputs:**

(using `...` to skip over some repetitive chunks)

Zero-padded hexadecimal:

```
00 00
01 01
...
7f 7f
80 -80
81 -7f
...
fe -02
ff -01
```

Binary with `,` and `;` for separators:

```
0,0;1,1;10,10;11,11;...;01111111,01111111;10000000,-10000000;10000001,-01111111;...;11111110,-00000010,11111111,00000001
```

Negadecimal with custom separators:

```
0 The HORSE is a noble animal. 0

1 The HORSE is a noble animal. 1

...

287 The HORSE is a noble animal. 287

288 The HORSE is a noble animal. 1932

289 The HORSE is a noble animal. 1933

...

354 The HORSE is a noble animal. 18

355 The HORSE is a noble animal. 19
```

Good luck!

Comment: Does the output have to be in the order `0..255`?

Comment: @Neil It needs to be in order, yes

Comment: Can there be leading separators?

Comment: @att Yes, that's fine

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), 30

```bash
(seq 0 127;seq -128 -1)|nl -v0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X6M4tVDBQMHQyNwaxNI1NLIAEpo1eTkKumUG//8DAA)

Comment: Nice use of `nl`!

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>54</s> <s>50</s> 47 bytes

```c
i;main(){for(;i<256;printf("%u,%hhd ",i++,i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOtPGyNTMuqAoM68kTUNJtVRHNSMjRUFJJ1NbWydTU9O69v9/AA)

### Explanation

```c
i;                      // Static variable initialized to 0
main() {
    for(;i<256;         // While the variable is <= 255:
        printf("%u,%hhd ",i++,i));
                        //     Output the original, then the char-coerced
                        //     value. Increment after use.
}
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 45 bytes

Non-portable, but 2 bytes shorter.

```c
f(i){for(i=-1;i++<255;printf("%u,%hhd ",i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPTVtfQOlNb28bI1NS6oCgzryRNQ0m1VEc1IyNFQUknU1PTuvZ/bmJmngZQvQaIAwA)

Comment: You have to print a conversion table, not create a conversion function

Comment: @pxeger Hopefully fixed.

Comment: [50 bytes using `%hhd`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SENXN9M608bI1Mw6U1tbs6AoM68kTUNJtVRHNSMjRUFJJ1MnU9O69v9/AA)

Comment: You can use a static zero-initialized variable instead of argc ([saves 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOtPGyNTMOlNbW7OgKDOvJE1DSbVURzUjI0VBSSdTJ1PTuvb/fwA))

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOtPGyNTMuqAoM68kTUNJtVRHNSMjRUFJJ1NbWydTU9O69v9/AA) (includes @Artyer 's advice).

Comment: [45 byte](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPTVtfQOlNb28bI1NRas6AoM68kTUNJtVRHNSMjRUFJJ1PTuvZ/bmJmngZQvQaIAwA) function

Comment: [Functions may output via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/81203)

Comment: @Artyer There's nothing wrong with arbitrary function names, [but functions must be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/58563).

Comment: Your undefined-behaviour version that only passes 1 arg after the format string doesn't work with `gcc -O2`.  It prints `0,-120 1,0 2,0 3,0 4,0 5,0 6,0 7,0 8,0 9,0 ...` on my x86-64 GNU/Linux system.  It does randomly happen to work with gcc -O0 debug builds.  It fails with `clang` even without optimization, so this isn't a C answer, it's an  "x86-64 gcc -O0" answer.  It also fails to work with `gcc -m32` even without optimization, because of course GCC doesn't push an extra copy of `i` onto the stack.  You should at least be mentioning how non-portable this is.

Comment: @peter-cordes It is code golf, the end justifies the means, even if it is writing blatantly non-portable code that falls apart even with `-O2`

Comment: @Easy: It's not just "non-portable", there's no C reason to *expect* it to work.  It's not taking advantage of a feature specific to some implementation, or an impl-defined behaviour or limit, which is the spirit of the "works on at least 1 implementation" rule.  Even the "no return" gcc -O0 sillyness has at least some generic cross-ISA GCC support: GCC -O0 seems to always evaluate expressions into the return-value register, at least at the end of functions, across a variety of targets.  But this is just pure coincidence of what some GCC version happened to do; breaks with `gcc -m32 -O0`

Comment: @EasyasPi: TL:DR: the language of the first block is mis-labelled as C (gcc).  It's actually "unoptimized x86-64 Linux gcc".  I'd leave C out of it because it's not even trying to be a valid C program, just compiler-generated asm that happens to do the job.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 18 bytes

Full program printing to stdout with `¯` as negative symbol. Requires 0-based indexing.

```apl
(⍳∘≢,⍪)…127,-128…1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@azzq3fyoY8ajzkU6j3pXaT5qWGZoZK6ja2hkAWL@B6r5XwAA)

`128…1` integers 128 through 1

`-` negate those

`127,` prepend 127

`…` fill integers from 0 until the first element of that (127)

`(`…`)` apply the tacit function:

`,⍪` columnify and prepend [a column consisting of]…

`⍳⍤≢` the **ɩ**ndices of the tally

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
⁹Ḷ_H%⁹żƊṢG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R486HO7bFe6gCGUf3HOt6uHOR@///AA)

*-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan*

### Explanation

```
⁹Ḷ_H%⁹żƊṢG   Main niladic link
⁹             256
 Ḷ            [0..255]
  _           Subtract
   H          half (of 256) = 128 => [-128..127]
       Ɗ      (
    %           Modulo
     ⁹          256
      ż         Zip with the list at the beginning of this inner link
       Ɗ      )
         Ṣ    Sort
          G   Format as a grid
```

Comment: 10 bytes by using zip, `ż` to avoid `€`: `⁹Ḷ_H%⁹żƊṢG` - [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R486HO7bFe6gCGUf3HOt6uHOR@///AA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! I totally forgot Jelly had a zip dyad.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```julia
r=0:255
@.println(r=>r%Int8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v8jWwMrI1JTLQa@gKDOvJCdPo8jWrkjVM6/EQvP/fwA)

Output format:

```julia
0 => 0
1 => 1...
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
for i in range(256):print i,127-i^127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8jUTNOqoCgzr0QhU8fQyFw3Mw5I/v8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>41</s> 40 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ovs*

Output format: `0,0 1,1 ... 255,-1`.

```javascript
f=n=>n>>8?'':[~~n,128+~n^127]+' '+f(-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7Pzs7CXl3dKrquLk/H0MhCuy4vztDIPFZbXUFdO01Dty5P839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Or maybe [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7Pzs7CXl3dKrquLk/H0MhCuy4vztDIXEdHJ1Y7TUO3Lk/zf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA) or even [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7Pzs7CXl3dKrquLk/H0MhCuy4vztDIPFY7TTtNQ7cuT/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoam5n8A) by abusing the loose output format. (But it's ugly.)

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                  // f is a recursive function
n =>                 // taking a counter n, which is initially undefined
  n >> 8 ?           // if n = 256:
    ''               //   stop the recursion
  :                  // else:
    [                //   build an array consisting of:
      ~~n,           //     the unsigned value (coerced to a number because
                     //     it's undefined on the first iteration)
      128 + ~n ^ 127 //     the signed value, which is (127 - n) XOR 127
                     //                              = (128 + (-n - 1)) XOR 127
    ]                //   end of array
    + ' '            //   coerce the array to a string and append a space
    + f(-~n)         //   append the result of a recursive call with n + 1
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7Pzs7CXl3dKrquLk/H0MhCuy4vztDIPFZbXUFdO01Dty5P839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA) with a slightly different formula.

Comment: @ovs Ah yes, nice one!

Comment: `f=n=>n>>8?'':[~~n,n<<24>>24]+' '+f(-~n)`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₅ÝƵQÝÂ±«ø»
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

Uses single spaces and newlines as delimiters for the output.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//@KChcOdxrVRw53DgsKxwqvDuMK7//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
₅Ý        # Push a list in the range [0,255]
ƵQÝ       # Push a list in the range [0,127]
   Â      # Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
    ±     # Get the bitwise-NOT of each (n → -n-1)
     «    # Merge the top two lists together
ø         # Create all possible pairs of the [0..255] and [0..127,-128..-1] lists
 »        # Join each pair by spaces, and then each string by newlines
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ƵQ` is `127`.

Comment: `-x-1` is the same as `~x`: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//@KChcOdxrVRw53DgsKxwqvDuMK7//8)

Comment: @ovs Ah, of course! So obvious now that I see it, but I totally missed it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
†szeŀ256Sṙohṡ128
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDguKq1KMNRqZmwQ93zszPeLhzoaGRxf//AA), [Another method](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///igKBz4bmgemVvzpjFgFPhuZlvaOG5oTEyOP//), [Another method](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr///igKBzwqd6ZW/FgERT4bmZb2jhuaExMjj//w)

### Explanation

```
†szeŀ256Sṙohṡ128
            ṡ128 symmetric range of 128 [-128...128]
          oh     remove last element
        Sṙ       rotate 128 spaces
    ŀ256         range [0...255]
  ze             zip the two, creating pairs
†s               convert all the numbers to strings
                 (can also be mw)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/) `-d:danger`, <strike>33</strike> 32 bytes

```
for b in 0..255:b.echo' ',b.int8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/Lb9IIUkhM0/BQE/PyNTUKkkvNTkjX11BXSdJLzOvxOL//3/JaTmJ6cX/dVOsUhLz0lOLAA)

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <strike>40</strike> 39 bytes

```
for b in 0..255:b.echo' ',cast[int8](b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/Lb9IIUkhM0/BQE/PyNTUKkkvNTkjX11BXSc5sbgkOjOvxCJWI0nz/38A)

Probably doesn't work on big-endian architectures.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
for(i in 0:255)cat(i,i-(i>127)*256,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwcDKyNRUMzmxRCNTJ1NXI9PO0MhcU8vI1EwnRPP/fwA)

Separator between converted numbers is " "; separator between each element of the list of conversions is " `TRUE`".  List is appended with a trailing separator (as allowed by the challenge rules).
"`TRUE`" is a pre-defined variable in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) that can be specified by a single character, `T`, and that has non-numeric output, so it's used as a convenient golfy separator here.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
cat(paste(0:255,c(0:127,-128:-1),'
'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgkVcPAysjUVCcZSBsamevoGhpZWOkaauqoc6lrav7/DwA), [Another approach](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgkVSPRRtfAysjUVCdR18jUTEsj0c7QyFxTR51LXVPz/38A)

Previous, slightly longer attempt, but with more-conventional separators (space & newline).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>47</s> 41 bytes

-6 thanks to @EasyasPi

```
print([(127-i^127,i)for i in range(256)])
```

Comment: [`-6` using the `127-i^127` trick the other snek friends are using](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI1rD0MhcNzMOSOpkaqblFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnahiZmmnGav7/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
unlines[show x++' ':show(x-x`div`128*256)|x<-[0..255]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfkpiUk2ob8780LyczL7U4ujgjv1yhQltbXUHdCsTWqNCtSEjJLEswNLLQMjI106ypsNGNNtDTMzI1jY39n5uYmWdbUFoSXFLkk6cANuz/v@S0nMT04v@6yQUFAA)

- Sadly `xor` is not in prelude module.
- Table is a string of pairs separated by newlines.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 61 bytes

Not very creative, but I think the shortest this can get.

```cs
for(var i=0;i<256;)System.Console.Write(i+$",{(sbyte)i++};");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IoyyxSCHT1sA608bI1MxaM7iyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyRVI1NbRUmnWqM4qbIkVTNTW7vWWknT@v9/AA)

This is a **complete** program thanks to C#9 and top-level statements. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgZgezACgG4EMwAICWBeABgG4cAeAJgFYA2IgSgFgAoLVrAAQEYA6AYQSgBnBABsAptwDqYHMDHIcAagAkAIgA0Ab2SCARgE85dJYoC+RVXSLMgA==)

Comment: [45 bytes using `Print`](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IoyyxSCHT1sA608bI1Mw6oCgzr0QjU1tFSadaozipsiRVM1Nbu1ZJU9P6/38A)

Comment: That's specifically `C# interactive`, post that as a seperate answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), 58 chars

```java
void f(){for(int i=0;i<256;out.println(i+" "+(byte)i++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBDoIwFATQfU/RsGptbIyJbqqngJ1xUaGQj/DblC8JIVzd2hjdzryZ3s5274PDvnkmGIOPxCeyBDXvc6UHi50ul4ncqHeGAZKLra0dr1b2c7OHho8WUJQUAbvb3cqVtUIatv1N@qKcra2PIr9wuB4MXI6ns/Ev0iEPaUABquCFEo@FnASlpDRb2tLbBwKPU6o@)

The `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `j`, <s>14</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
₈ʁ₇ʁḂꜝJZ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%82%88%CA%81%E2%82%87%CA%81%E1%B8%82%EA%9C%9DJZ&inputs=&header=&footer=)

[OP says it's allowable](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56815478#56815478)

*-5 bytes due to porting 05AB1E*

### Explained

```
₈ʁ₇ʁḂꜝJZ
₈ʁ         # Push range [0, 256)
  ₇ʁḂ      # Push [0, 128) and (128, 0]
     ꜝ     # Bit-not over that last copy
      JZ   # Merge and zip
           # The j flag joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 15 bytes

```
₈‹ʀ₇‹ʀḂN₇NpJZvṄ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%82%88%E2%80%B9%CA%80%E2%82%87%E2%80%B9%CA%80%E1%B8%82N%E2%82%87NpJZv%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: There's already an [8 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217807/79857) answer in Vyxal `j`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>49</s> <s>53</s></sup> 51 bytes

Saved 2 bytes taking a peek at [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217621/9481)!!!
Added 8 bytes to fix a rule violation kindly pointed out by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
f=lambda i=255:i*' 'and'%d '*2%(i,127-i^127)+f(i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdPWyNTUKlNLXUE9MS9FXTVFQV3LSFUjU8fQyFw3Mw5IamqnaWTqGmr@LyjKzCvRSNPQ1PwPAA)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdPWyNTUKlNLXUE9MS9FXTVFQV3LSFUjU8fQyFw3Mw5IamqnaWTqGmr@LyjKzCvRSNPQ1PwPAA) by shortening the base case and using the repetition in the formatting string.

Comment: @ovs Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 34 bytes

```powershell
0..255|%{"$($_;($_-bxor128)-128)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8jUtEa1WklFQyXeGoh1kyryiwyNLDR1QYRS7f//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>29</s> 33 bytes

+4 bytes: fit to the task rules. Thanks @Zaelin Goodman

```powershell
0..127+-128..-1|%{"$(($i++);$_)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz9DIXFvX0MhCT0/XsEa1WklFQ0MlU1tb01olXlOp9v9/AA)

Comment: You have to also print the number being converted from; and array outputs are explicitly forbidden: `The output must be textual; returning arrays/lists/dictionaries is not allowed`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
V256++Nd-J127xNJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8zI1Exb2y9F18vQyLzCz@v/fwA)

-1 byte thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman)!

---

Python 3.8 translation:

```
for N in range(256):print(str(N)+" "+str((J:=127)-N^J))
```

Comment: Using `J` to reuse 127 should save a byte. Also, if not for the output restriction could save [a byte by using `B`](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30fXy9DIvCLJq9LJ18jU7P9/AA).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks, I didn't realize JK assignment also returned the assigned value!

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
()=>for(i<-0 to 255)print(s"$i,${i.toByte} ")
```

Output format: `0,0 1,1 2,2 ... 127,127 128,-128 129,-127 ... 253,-3 254,-2 255,-1`  with `,` and   for separators.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEAXQfU/xKV3MgIoI3Ygp1L1LDzCtEUZCEppBlNKzx4XvAK/MEqSm6eVnw000wn/Mx0fBmDPWBnhLgMkU/BnEcAPuUQ2uErvhmRbSy/4ISzj1PedFo1FpO911qx4sXb/mN7Rc8T@Im63@AA)

**Edit**: Due to conventions, the String Interpolator `f` was changed to `s`. Thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)!

---

#### 37 bytes

... if ignoring the seperator rule.

```
()=>for(i<-0 to 255)print(i,i.toByte)
```

Output format: `(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(...)(127,127)(128,-128)(129,-127)(...)(253,-3)(254,-2)(255,-1)` with `,` and `)(` for separators, but unfortunately also with a leading `(` and trailing `)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxCsJAEAXQPqf45QxEESFNcAOmt/QAk2SEkWV3SQZRgmdfC1//tlmi1Dw9dXbcxBL07ZqWDddSsDfASyJcpqg9iBEG3JM5QiUOwyOvZJfDCZ5x7jouqyUna@3oefy4csX/Ejff@gM)

Comment: Nice! Btw, s is usually used instead of f.

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, <s>48</s> 45 bytes

*Lowered to 45 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217614/print-a-conversion-table-for-unsigned-bytes/217641?noredirect=1#comment507707_217641).*

```
BEGIN{for(;i<256;i++)print +i,i<128?+i:i-256}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9IwzrTxsjUzDpTW1uzoCgzr0RBO1Mn08bQyMJeO9MqUxcoV/v/PwA)

Had to workaround the fact that bitwise functions in GNU AWK don't accept negative arguments. Anyway, this should work on any AWK implementation.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9IwzrTxsjUzDpTW1uzoCgzr0RBO1Mn08bQyMJeO9MqUxcoV/v/PwA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - Clearly I was overthinking that last bit.

Comment: It seems [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) requires parenthesis around the conditional's test expression.  Note also that no AWK I've tried requires the unary `+` operators on any of the print arguments.

Comment: Also, all versions of AWK I've tried will initialize variables to `1`, not zero as required.

Comment: @GregA.Woods - Thanks for your comment! I should've said it _might_ work on any AWK implementation. I have not tested it in One True Awk, but it seems the ternary conditional can really add one more byte. On the `+`, I did it to show the first `0`s, because `i` is parsed as empty string while not defined.

Comment: Ah, yes, I agree:  The `+` will save one character of source v.s. initializing to zero.  Note though that this trick of coercing the initial blank string to a zero will not work in older versions, including for example `nawk` from the Heirloom tools (which is arguably a bug in the older versions).  This seems to have been fixed only since it was migrated to GitHub, probably in the changes dated 2018-08-22, so making it truly portable would still (and for a long time to come) require the explicit initialization to an integer.

Comment: Just to be more pedantic I'll also note that the original AWK (from 7th Edition Unix) did not support the `?:` conditional ternary operator.  (That version is also available in the Heirloom tools as `oawk`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
256.times{|i|puts [i,127-i^127]*' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38jUTK8kMze1uLoms6agtKRYITpTx9DIXDczDkjGaqkrqNf@/w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 37 bytes

```
0[$$$$256=~][128>[256-]?\.44,.10,1+]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/98gWgUIjEzNbOtiow2NLOyigWzdWPsYPRMTHT1DAx1D7Vjl//8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
for i in range(256):print(i,127-i^127)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8jUTNOqoCgzr0QjU8fQyFw3Mw5Iav7/DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 64 bytes

```php
<?php for($x=0;$x<256;$x++){echo$x.','.($x<128?$x:$x-256).";";}
```

```php
<?php for($x = 0; $x < 256; $x++){ #Go through each number
  echo $x . ',' . #Write x, then...
($x < 128 ? $x #if x is less than 128, write x again, 
: $x - 256) . ";";  #otherwise write x - 256 
}
```

Uses ',' and '.' as separators.

Comment: You not have to count the `<?php` tag as long as your code is runnable by `php -r`; as the loop repeats a single instruction, no need for the braces; if you output separate values instead of concatenating them, the parenthesis are not necessary either; you can move the incrementing of the counter to the `echo`, just need to change the range. BTW, if you use a literal newline character the output is more readable at the same length. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQqbHUNrVUqbIxMTa01U5Mz8rW1VSp0lIAQKGhoZGGvUmGlUqFrZGqmo8SlZP3/PwA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: Using expression instead of the ternary operator allows squeezing it a bit more. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVKmyMTM2sNVOTM/K1VSp0lIBQpUJbWxcoqqWhUmFnaGShqaPEpWT9/z8A "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 43 bytes

```
256 iota [ dup pprint bl 8 >signed . ] each
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCsJAEAXQq/wTpBAiYsBWbGzESiwmm68ZjLvrzoTg6deA9XsPCZ5KvV5O5@Mexs/MGGh4sUROyIXu31w0OjThLT42vfqiRohZCoaubtrtii64YZgz8r/3E3Y4mD4jBzS4gxLGWn8)

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 30 bytes

```
range(256)|[.,(128+.)%256-128]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPI1EyzJlpPR8PQyEJbT1MVyNcFMmP///@XX1CSmZ9X/F83DwA)

output format:

```
[
  0,
  0
]
...
[
  255,
  -1
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 45 bytes

```
repeat n 256[print[p: n - 1 p xor 128 - 128]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78otSA1sUQhT8HI1Cy6oCgzryS6wArI1VUwVChQqMgvUjA0sgDxjCxiY///BwA)

Uses @Arnauld's formula

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

```perl
say"$_ ",$_-2*($_&128)for 0..255
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJJV5BSUclXtdIS0MlXs3QyEIzLb9IwUBPz8gUqOJffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```rust
||for i in 0..256{print!("{}:{}
",i,i as i8)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQvaf4uVIQiaCIpMO0SBioKdRW6tmn99KXi0TGfRAbW6@zIGKHtBafBAIxRu@nealvIi6D0bVvtSvtyBGODFptl6CisUF1@QE)

Note the newline literal, output format is

```rust
1:1
2:2
...
```

This prints the loop count as both an `i32` and an `i8`. Note that as casts are not allowed to panic, so they may result in unexpected behavior on overflow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
ＩＥ⁺…⁰⊗℅@…±⊗℅@⁰⟦κι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQCMgp7RYIygxLz1Vw0BHwSW/NCknNUXDvyglMy8xR0PJQUlTU1NHAaLALzU9sSRVA5ciAxARna2jkBkL5Fv///9ftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs in decimal with single and double newline as separators. Explanation:

```
   …                 Range from
    ⁰                Literal `0` to
       @            Literal string `@`
      ℅             ASCII code i.e. 64
     ⊗              Doubled i.e. 128
  ⁺                 Concatenated with
        …           Range from
            @       Literal string `@`
           ℅        ASCII code
          ⊗         Doubled
         ±          Negated
             ⁰      To literal `0`
 Ｅ                  Map over values
               κ    Current index
                ι   Current value
              ⟦     Wrap in list
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
256$*_¶
_
$.` -$.'¶
128`-.+
$%`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8jUXEUrnsvQyMIuIZ5LRS9BQVdFT/3QNi4IB4iBbCNTM/eE//8B) Uses space and newline as the delimiters, plus adds a variety of trailing spaces and newlines. Explanation:

```
256$*_¶
```

Insert 256 `_`s plus a newline which is used to balance out the number of characters after each `_`.

```
_
$.` -$.'¶
```

Replace each `_` with a line giving the number of preceding and (with a minus sign) following characters.

```
128`-.+
$%`
```

Replace the first 128 minus numbers with the number that precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
Print@i@Mod[i,256,-128]~Do~{i,0,255}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCHTwTc/JTpTx8jUTEfX0Mgits4lv646U8cAKGJa@/8/AA)

Comment: Perhaps `{#,Mod[#,256,-128]}&/@Range[0,255]` for 34 bytes, since the answer can be returned as well?

Comment: @GregMartin Returning lists is specifically disallowed; adding a `StringRiffle` would make your answer longer than the original.

Comment: woops I didn't read the OP carefully enough :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

An alternative to @KjetilS's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217625/72767) of the same length.

```perl
say$_,$",unpack c,chr for 0..255
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlXkdFSac0ryAxOVshWSc5o0ghLb9IwUBPz8gUqOJffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 35 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;i<256;)print(i,i++<<24>>24)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z8tv0gj09bAOtPGyNTMWrOgKDOvRCNTJ1Nb28bGyMTOzshE8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
disp([0:255;0:127 -128:-1]')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QCPawMrI1NTawMrQyFxB19DIwkrXMFZd8/9/AA)

I'm not sure if `disp()` could be removed or not...

Answer (score 1):

## Deadfish~, 15587 bytes

```
{{i}ddddd}ddc{d}ddddddccccc{i}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dc{d}{d}iiiccccc{i}{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}c{d}{d}iiccccc{i}{i}ddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}ic{d}{d}iccccc{i}{i}dc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iic{d}{d}ccccc{i}{i}c{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{d}{d}dccccc{i}{i}ic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{d}{d}ddccccc{i}{i}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{d}{d}dddccccc{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{d}{d}ddddccccc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}dddc{d}{d}dddddccccc{i}{i}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dcdc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}dddcdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dcc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}dddcc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dcic{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}dddcic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciic{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}dddciic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciiic{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}dddciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiic{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}dddciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiic{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}dddciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}dddciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddc{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}dddc{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddc{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}dddc{i}ddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}cddc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}ddcddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}cdc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}ddcdc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}cc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}ddcc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}cic{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}ddcic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}ciic{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}ddciic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ciiic{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}ddciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}ciiiic{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}ddciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}ciiiiic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}ddciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}ciiiiiic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}ddciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}c{i}dddc{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}ddc{i}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}icdddc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}dcdddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}icddc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}dcddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}icdc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}dcdc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}icc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}dcc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}icic{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}dcic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iciic{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}dciic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iciiic{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}dciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iciiiic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}dciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iciiiiic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}dciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iciiiiiic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}dciiiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iicddddc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}cddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}iicdddc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}cdddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}iicddc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}cddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}iicdc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}cdc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iicc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}cc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iicic{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}cic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiciic{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}ciic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiciiic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}ciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiciiiic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}ciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiciiiiic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}ciiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiicdddddc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}icdddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}iiicddddc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}icddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}iiicdddc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}icdddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}iiicddc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}icddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iiicdc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}icdc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiicc{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}icc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiicic{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}icic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiciic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}iciic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiciiic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}iciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiciiiic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}iciiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiicddddddc{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}iicddddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}iiiicdddddc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}iicdddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}iiiicddddc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}iicddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}iiiicdddc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}iicdddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iiiicddc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}iicddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiiicdc{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}iicdc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiiicc{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}iicc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiicic{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}iicic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiciic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}iiciic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiciiic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}iiciiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{d}iiic{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}iiic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}iiiiicddddddc{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}iiicddddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}iiiiicdddddc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}iiicdddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}iiiiicddddc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}iiicddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iiiiicdddc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}iiicdddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiicddc{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}iiicddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiicdc{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}iiicdc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiicc{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}iiicc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiicic{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}iiicic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiciic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}iiiciic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{d}iic{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}iiiic{d}iic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{d}iiic{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}iiiic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicddddddc{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}iiiicddddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicdddddc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}iiiicdddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicddddc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}iiiicddddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicdddc{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}iiiicdddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicddc{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}iiiicddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicdc{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}iiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicc{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}iiiicc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiicic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}iiiicic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}ddddd}dddc{d}ic{d}ddddddcccc{i}{i}iiiiic{d}ic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{d}iic{d}{d}iiicccc{i}{i}iiiiic{d}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}dddc{d}iiic{d}{d}iicccc{i}{i}iiiiic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dddcddddddc{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}iiiiicddddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}dddcdddddc{d}{d}cccc{i}{i}iiiiicdddddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}dddcddddc{d}{d}dcccc{i}{i}iiiiicddddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}dddcdddc{d}{d}ddcccc{i}{i}iiiiicdddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}dddcddc{d}{d}dddcccc{i}{i}iiiiicddc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}dddcdc{d}{d}ddddcccc{i}{i}iiiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}dddcc{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}iiiiicc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dcdcc{d}ddddddccc{i}{i}dddcdcc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dcdcic{d}{d}iiiccc{i}{i}dddcdcic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dcdciic{d}{d}iiccc{i}{i}dddcdciic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dcdciiic{d}{d}iccc{i}{i}dddcdciiic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dcdciiiic{d}{d}ccc{i}{i}dddcdciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dcdciiiiic{d}{d}dccc{i}{i}dddcdciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dcdciiiiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}{i}dddcdciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dcdc{i}dddc{d}{d}dddccc{i}{i}dddcdc{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dcdc{i}ddc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}{i}dddcdc{i}ddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dcdc{i}dc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}{i}dddcdc{i}dc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dccdc{d}ddddddccc{i}{i}dddccdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dccc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}{i}dddccc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dccic{d}{d}iiccc{i}{i}dddccic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dcciic{d}{d}iccc{i}{i}dddcciic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dcciiic{d}{d}ccc{i}{i}dddcciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dcciiiic{d}{d}dccc{i}{i}dddcciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dcciiiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}{i}dddcciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dcciiiiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}{i}dddcciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dcc{i}dddc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dcc{i}ddc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}{i}dddcc{i}ddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dcicddc{d}ddddddccc{i}{i}dddcicddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dcicdc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}{i}dddcicdc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dcicc{d}{d}iiccc{i}{i}dddcicc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dcicic{d}{d}iccc{i}{i}dddcicic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciciic{d}{d}ccc{i}{i}dddciciic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciciiic{d}{d}dccc{i}{i}dddciciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciciiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}{i}dddciciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciciiiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}{i}dddciciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciciiiiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiiciciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dcic{i}dddc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiiciciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciicdddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiiciciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciicddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiiciciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciicdc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiiciciic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciicc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiicicic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciicic{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiicicc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciiciic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiicicdc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dciiciiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiicicddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dciiciiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiiciiiicc{i}ddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dciiciiiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiicc{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiciiiiiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiicciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiicddddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiicciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiicdddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiicciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciiicddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiicciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciiicdc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiicciic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciiicc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiiccic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciiicic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiiccc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dciiiciic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiiccdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dciiiciiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiiciiiicdc{i}dc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dciiiciiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiicdc{i}ddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiciiiiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiicdc{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiicdddddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiicdciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiicddddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiicdciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiicdddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiicdciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiicddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiicdciiic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciiiicdc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiicdciic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciiiicc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiicdcic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dciiiicic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiicdcc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiciic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}iicc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiciiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}iicdc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiciiiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}iicddc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicddddddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}iicdddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicdddddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}iicddddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicddddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}iicdddddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicdddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}iicddddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicddc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}iic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicdc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}iic{d}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicc{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}iic{d}ic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiicic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}icic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiciic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}icc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiciiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}icdc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiic{d}iiic{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}icddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicddddddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}icdddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicdddddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}icddddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicddddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}icdddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicdddc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}icddddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicddc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}ic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicdc{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}ic{d}iic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicc{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}ciic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiicic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}cic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dciiiiiiciic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}cc{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddc{d}iic{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}cdc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddc{d}iiic{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}cddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcddddddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}cdddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcdddddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}cddddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcddddc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}cdddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcdddc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}cddddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcddc{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}c{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcdc{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}dciiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}dciic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}dddcic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}dcic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddc{d}ic{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}dcc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddc{d}iic{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}dcdc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddc{d}iiic{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}dcddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcddddddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}dcdddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcdddddc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}dcddddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcddddc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}dcdddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcdddc{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}dcddddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcddc{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}ddciiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcdc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}ddciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dc{i}ddcc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}ddciic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}cddcc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}ddcic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}cddcic{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}ddcc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}cddciic{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}ddcdc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}cddciiic{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}ddcddc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}cddciiiic{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}ddcdddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}cddciiiiic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}ddcddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}cddciiiiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}ddcdddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}cddc{i}dddc{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}dddciiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}cddc{i}ddc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}dddciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}cddc{i}dc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}dddciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}cdcdc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}dddciic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}cdcc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}dddcic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}cdcic{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}dddcc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}cdciic{d}{d}iccc{i}iiic{i}dddcdc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}cdciiic{d}{d}ccc{i}iiic{i}dddcddc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}cdciiiic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiic{i}dddcdddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}cdciiiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiic{i}dddcddddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}cdciiiiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiiciiiiiiciiiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}cdc{i}dddc{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiiciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}cdc{i}ddc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiiciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}ccddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiiciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}ccdc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiiiiciic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}ccc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiiiicic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ccic{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiiiicc{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}cciic{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}cciiic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiiiicddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}cciiiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiiiicdddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}cciiiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiiciiiiic{i}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}cciiiiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}cc{i}dddc{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}cicdddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiiiciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}cicddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiiiciiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}cicdc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiiiciic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}cicc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiiicic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}cicic{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiiicc{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}ciciic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ciciiic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiiicddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}ciciiiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiiciiiic{i}ddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}ciciiiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiiciiiic{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}ciciiiiiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiiciiiiciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}ciicddddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiiciiiiciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}ciicdddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiiciiiiciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}ciicddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiiciiiiciiic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ciicdc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiiciic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}ciicc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiicic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}ciicic{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiicc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ciiciic{d}{d}ddccc{i}iiiciiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}ciiciiic{d}{d}dddccc{i}iiic{i}iic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}ciiciiiic{d}{d}ddddccc{i}iiic{i}ic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}ciiciiiiic{d}{d}dddddccc{i}iiic{i}c{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}ciiicdddddc{d}ddddddccc{i}iiic{i}dc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}ciiicddddc{d}{d}iiiccc{i}iiic{i}ddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}ciiicdddc{d}{d}iiccc{i}iiic{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ciiicddc{d}{d}iccc{i}iiiciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}ciiicdc{d}{d}ccc{i}iiiciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}ciiicc{d}{d}dccc{i}iiiciiiic
```